# Using Azure Bing Search API in Android

Tags: android, image, search, azure, bing

I am trying to make an app which executes an image search and displays the image results in a grid. Since the Google Image Search API is deprecated and will no longer be available shortly, I am trying to use the Bing Search API.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:427)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
```

I am following the example in http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-bing-custom-search-inside-your.html. If anyone has experienced this issue, or can help me out, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code thus far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> () {

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

                //  Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=penguin");
                //  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                //  startActivity(intent);

                /*-------------------------Bing search-------------------------*/
                String searchText = "Hello World";
                searchText = searchText.replace(" ", "%20");
                String accountKey = "MY_APP_ID";
                accountKey = accountKey.replace("+", "%2B");

                byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
                String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
                URL url;
                try {

                    url = new URL(
                            "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/"
                                    + "Image?Query=%27" + searchText + "%27");

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            (conn.getInputStream())));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String output;
                    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(output);
                    }

                    conn.disconnect();

                    System.out.println(sb);

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        task.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you are still working on this. But, you should check the basics of Android first. There are many mistakes in your code that only come from experience. If you fix them, I might help you with your question.

Comment: can u please send me this code

Comment: @kumar, what do you mean? The code is right here. I've been busy on other projects and haven't come back to this yet. Luis, I am not new to Android; this code comes from a sample project. However, when I do get back to this, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @lgdroid57 i mean you said that, i am following the example in http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-bing-custom-search-inside-your.html. u did this task by using java tutorial ,now i have same requirement but i am unable to to this,if u come back it is more helpful for me,thanks for ur response

Comment: Have you solved it? If you did, an answer would be appreciated...

Comment: Hi @Pinhassi. I have not solved it yet; I've been working on other projects. However, I do mean to look at this again over the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
public class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

private String mSearchStr;
private int mNumOfResults = 0;

private Callback mCallback;
private BingSearchResults mBingSearchResults;
private Error mError;

public SearchAsyncTask(String searchStr, int numOfResults, Callback callback) {
    mSearchStr = searchStr;
    mNumOfResults = numOfResults;
    mCallback = callback;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        String searchStr = URLEncoder.encode(mSearchStr);
        String numOfResultsStr = mNumOfResults <= 0 ? "" : "&$top=" + mNumOfResults;
        String bingUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=%27" + searchStr + "%27" + numOfResultsStr + "&$format=json";
        String accountKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
        String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);

        URL url = null;
        url = new URL(bingUrl);

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);
        InputStream response = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        String res = readStream(response);

        Gson gson = (new GsonBuilder()).create();
        mBingSearchResults = gson.fromJson(res, BingSearchResults.class);

        Log.d(TAG, res);
        //conn.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mError = new Error(e.getMessage(), e);
        //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (mCallback != null) {
        mCallback.onComplete(mBingSearchResults, mError);
    }

}

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();


}
public interface Callback {
void onComplete(Object o, Error error);
}
    }
```

To parse the result:

```
public class BingSearchResults {

public ResultsContent d;

public static class ResultsContent {
    public Result[] results;
    public String __next;
}

public static class Result {
    public String ID;
    public String Title;
    public String Description;
    public String DisplayUrl;
    public String Url;
    public Metadata __metadata;

}

public static class Metadata {
    public String uri;
    public String type;
}

public Result[] getResults(){
    if (d == null)
        return null;
    return d.results;
}

public String getNextUrl(){
    if (d == null)
        return null;
    return d.__next;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return (d == null || d.results == null || d.results.length == 0);
}

public int size(){
    if (d == null || d.results == null)
        return 0;
    return d.results.length;
}
}
```

You also need to include the external jars commons-codec-1.9.jar and gson-2.2.4.jar

Comment: Oh, sweet! Thanks! I'll have a look!

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak a few things for Image Results (vs Web Results), but this was very helpful. Once I've cleaned up the code, I will try to post my revised code.

Comment: @igdroid57 could you post what you ended up with?

Answer (score 0):

Little bit change occur in this code sometimes compilation bug of encoder generate problem `byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());`